# Firefox 56 cut off text with any custom font

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-fonts

Look at to this screenshot:

[Screenshot - Browser view and Firebug/CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh0pX.jpg)

[image]

The left side is with minimal CSS. On the right with all my CSS.

When I change some settings in firebug or resize the browser window, the text is displayed correctly.

I have tested it on 2 other PCs, all other browsers 
working fine and the Edge console doesn't display any error.

NOTE:
font-family:f1 is just a short name for my google font.

Anyone can help me to understand why I have this problem in firefox? 
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can force a css redraw by adding `overflow: auto`.

Comment: doesn't work JoostS. And thx for the edit Kalamarico!

Comment: I would like to look into it. Can you create a codepen illustrating the problem?

Comment: I can try it tomorow.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Simply close the Firefox Development Tools and refresh the page...

Edit:
I have a 4k Monitor and both, website and Development Tools in a fullHD window. I tested it now on a normal fullHD Screen. Its the same Problem. When I open the Tools and reload the page, the text cuts off